# Why is "mit meiner kleinen Wohnung" correct?

Tags: adjective, dative, adjective-ending

"Ich begnüge mich mit meiner kleinen Wohnung" appears to be a correct sentence in german.

It confuses me that it is not rather "Ich begnüge mich mit meiner kleine**r** Wohnung" instead.

Comment: https://www.germanveryeasy.com/adjective-declension#Mixed-declension

Comment: Possessive articles such as "mein" require the [mixed declension](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/klein#Declension). Voting to close.

Comment: Hi Ni69a! Welcome to german.SE! Your question has been closed, because the community has decided not to answer questions which can be answered by a conjugation table. However, it doesn't mean that the community wasn't willing to help. If your question goes beyond what can be looked up in a dictionary, please edit it and explain what's still unclear. This will help us answer your actual question and might lead to your question being reopened. Please have a look at https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/628/how-do-i-ask-good-on-topic-questions-about-meaning-translations-or-difference